# Как сохранять игровой прогресс игрока в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть игрок и у него есть список оружия. Когда он заходит в магазин после смены уровня, магазин должен знать какие у игрока имеются купленные оружия: какие оружия он еще не купил, какие оружия ему еще недоступны для покупки и исходя от этих данных отображать товары в магазине.
**Вопрос:** как именно реализовать хранение данных о инвентаре игрока? Где сохранять данные чтобы они не стерлись после смены сцены? 
У меня в голове пока единственный вариант - все эти данные сохранять в `PlayersPref`, но думаю это слишком топорно, так как объем данных большой и всё это пихать в префы не очень эффективно.
Как лучше всего это реализовать? Сложные и замудренные решения я не осилю, так как я еще новичок в программировании и юнити. 
Может быть подскажите в каких туториалах освещаются эти темы?
**Я планирую делать под мобильные устройства**, а там вроде как есть гугл плей сервисы, может быть в ту сторону смотреть?
P.S ES2 не подойдет, так как он платный, а деньги у игроделов не водятся))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `PlayersPref` использовать надо только для хранения небольших данных вроде настроек и т.п.
2. Прогресс и подобные вещи лучше хранить либо в файлах, либо в SQLite базе, если не нужно синхронизировать между устройствами.
3. Вы вот про ES2 упомянули, значит вы хотите сделать сохранение прогресса между устройствами? Тогда можно нативные штуки использовать. Если вам нужно только для Google Play, то используйте плагин [Google Play Games plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity), почитайте там про реализацию [Saved Games](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#saving-game-state-to-the-cloud). Заодно почитайте [официальную документацию](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames).

Comment: под iOS Google Play Games plugin не подойдет? Я хочу сделать сохранение между устройствами и между сценами. Чтобы когда я заканчивал уровень я сохранял свои деньги, экипировку и шел в магазин покупать новые вещи. Мне нужно всё это сохранять

Comment: Раньше можно было, но больше не рекомендуется использовать это под iOS https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/focusing-our-google-play-games-services.html

Comment: Вы сказали то что можно использовать нативные штуки - можно поподробнее? Может есть ссылка на статью где описывается как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов для Android это https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames. Для iOS не могу сказать, я с ним плотно никогда не работал.